# Syncano v4 Error: "You do not have permission to perform this action"

Tags: python, syncano

Using the Syncano v4 Python Library, I attempted to do the following:

```
book_class = instance.classes.create(
  name='book',
  schema='[{"name": "title", "type": "string"}, {"name": "author", "type": "string"}]’
)
```

And received this error:

```
syncano.exceptions.SyncanoRequestError: 403 You do not have permission to perform this action.
```

I'm currently using the instance API key - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`403` in the response usually means you are trying to access an endpoint with either non-existing key or wrong type of key.

In this case - you cannot create classes using instance api key - using your account key is necessary. If you don't have it, you can always check it in the dashboard, or just use https://api.syncano.io/v1/account/auth/ endpoint to log in (or use api explorer: http://docs.syncano.com/v0.1/docs/account-log-in, account key will be in the response, once you pass your credentials).

Once you have your account key, you should use it to connect to your syncano instance:

```
import syncano
from syncano.models.base import Class

connection = syncano.connect(api_key="ACCOUNT_KEY")

book_class = Class.please.create(
    instance_name='INSTANCE_NAME',
    name='books',
    schema=[
        {"name": "title", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "author", "type": "string"}
    ])
```

If account key and instance name are correct this code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the account key to create new classes. You can also use the Syncano GUI to make them. More info is on that [here](http://docs.syncano.com/v4.0/docs/authentication). Hope that helps